# Relative Dimension of Vector Space Over Two Fields

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $K$ and $L$ be fields, with $L$ a vector space over $K$, and $V$ a vector space over both $K$ and $L$. Suppose also that their actions are compatible, so
$$k\cdot(l\cdot v)=(k\cdot l)\cdot v$$

I am trying to show the following:

> If $\dim_KL=\dim_KV=n$, then $\dim_LV=1$.

We must have isomorphisms $\varphi:L\to K^n$ and $\psi:K^n\to V$ of $K$-modules. Then $\psi\circ\varphi:L\to V$ is also an isomorphism of $K$-modules.

However I can't seem to show that it is $L$-linear also, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take $v$ any non zero vector of $V$, then $L.v=\{\ell.v|\ell \in L\}$ is certainly a sub-$K$ vector space of $V$ by your assumption, and it is clearly $K$-isomorphic to $L$, therefore it has the same dimension over $K$ as $V$, and is thus equal to $V$. This means that $v$ generates $V$ as an $L$-space and is of dimension 1.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment, it's made everything clear for me now. If you'd like to post this an answer I'd be more than happy to accept it

Comment: Sorry @Ahr, I just have one question about your comment. In showing that $L\cong Lv$ as $K$-vector spaces, are we assuming then that $k\cdot(l\cdot v)=l\cdot(k\cdot v)$ so that $l\mapsto lv$ is $K$-linear?

Comment: No, the $K$-linearity is saying that $k.(\ell.v)=(k.\ell).v$ which is your hypothesis (and the additivity which is part of the $L$-vector space structure on $V$).

Comment: Of course, sorry about that, I've really managed to confuse myself! Thanks again for your comment 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm paraphrasing Ahr's comment as an answer so that I can accept it, if they would like to post one themselves then I am happy to remove it.

---

Let $v\in V$ be any non-zero vector. Then $Lv$ is a $K$-vector subspace of $V$ since the actions are compatible.

We have $L\cong Lv$ as $K$-vector spaces via $l\mapsto lv$, this map is $K$-linear again since the actions are compatible.

Then
$$\dim_K(Lv)=\dim_K(L)=\dim_K(V)$$
and so we must have $Lv=V$ since $Lv\subseteq V$.

This shows that $v$ generates $V$ as an $L$-vector space, and so $\dim_L(V)=1$ as desired.